# Retrieve data from a Polygon using osmnx

Tags: python, python-3.x, polygon, osmnx

I want to access the data that corresponds to Continental Portugal (the part next to spain, therefore excluding the islands), using osmnx:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString, Polygon
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from descartes import PolygonPatch
from IPython.display import IFrame
ox.config(log_console=True, use_cache=True)
```

Selected the place. I obtained the MultiPolygon that corresponded to Portugal

```
place = 'Portugal'
G = ox.gdf_from_place(place)
fig, ax = ox.plot_shape(G, figsize=(17,17))
```

I only want Continental Portugal,what I mean by this is only the part next to spain and exclude the islands like Azores and Madeira. Therefore I explored the geometry of the MultipPolygon. And then sorted all the Polygons by area and picked the one with the largest area.

```
exploded_G = G.explode()
exploded_G['area'] = exploded_G.area
exploded_G.sort_values(by='area', inplace=True)
Portugal= exploded_G.iloc[-1]['geometry']
```

My question is: How can I access all the information such as points of interest, roads, nodes, etc of the Polygon I have now (the one I called Portugal).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since continental Portugal involves a lot of data and hence is time-consuming, I just implemented the following steps on one of the smaller polygons. So the following should work on 'Portugal' as well.

```
exploded_gdf_place = gdf_place.explode()
exploded_gdf_place['area'] = exploded_gdf_place.area
exploded_gdf_place.sort_values(by='area', inplace=True)
smaller_area_Portugal= exploded_gdf_place.iloc[4]['geometry']
```

You could use OSMNx's `graph_from polygon` function to obtain the road network (for example, driving or walking network).

```
g = ox.graph_from_polygon(polygon = smaller_area_Portugal, network_type = 'drive')
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(g, fig_height=5)
```

You may then obtain data with regards to the nodes and edges of the same graph as geodataframes as follows.

```
gdf_nodes,gdf_edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(g, nodes=True, edges=True)
```

For obtaining data regarding POIs within the polygon, you should use the following. I have not specified any particular amenity type, but that can also be done. Refer to the docs.

```
gdf_pois = ox.pois.osm_poi_download(polygon=smaller_area_Portugal)
```

One example of an obtained POI within the polygon is to be retrieved as follows.

```
sample_poi = gdf_pois['elements'][0]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that is exactly what I wanted !